# how to change the content of progress dialog at runtime?

Tags: android, dialog

I need to change the content of progress dialog when sync activity is running it shows "synchronizing data"
when it has completed it goes for another background activity and still shows the same text what I want is to change the text when it goes to other background task?

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
        mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(viewContext, "", "Synchronizing Data",
                true);

    };

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
     */
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        if (type.contains("ferry")) {
            return SynchronizeRepositoryFerry(false);

        } else {
            boolean value = SynchronizeRepositories(false, initialSync);
            mDialog.setTitle("Loading Images");//FROM HERE I WANT TO CHANGE DIALOG

            com.jumbybay.businessobjects.User user = new com.jumbybay.businessobjects.User();
            DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(viewContext);
            IUserRepository repository = dbHelper.getUserRepository();
            List<com.jumbybay.businessobjects.User> imageList;
            try {
                int id;
                String url = "http://i.zdnet.com/blogs/3-29-androids.jpg";
                imageList = repository.Retrieve();
                for (int i = 0; i < imageList.size(); i++) {
                    user = imageList.get(i);
                    // url = user.getPicture();
                    id = user.getId();
                    fetchImage fetch = new fetchImage();
                    fetch.savesd(id, url);

                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block// url = user.getPicture();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return value;

        }

    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        mDialog.setTitle("lOADING IMAGES...");

    }
    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        this.syncComplete = result;
        mDialog.dismiss();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(viewContext, classType);
        viewContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: are you using 2 background tasksks for this pourpouse show some code

Comment: If you're using two async tasks, you can change the text in the `onPostExecute` method of the first task. If it's a single task, use `onProgressUpdate()`

Comment: I am using same background task

Comment: in same doinbackground I need to change the text

Comment: put the whole code showing on post execute and pre execute

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using it like this

```
mDialog.setTitle("Loading Images");
 mDialog.show();
```

Comment: I can't do that in background task

Comment: that's because you haven't declared it public declare prgrs dilog n public